# Why has reputation reduced on my Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

Yesterday I had seen 7448 reputation points on my Stack Overflow account.

But today it has reduced to [7421 points](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488433/bharath). This is not first time. I think last month also same thing had happened.  There is no down votes/unaccepted answer. Then How did this happen?

Comment: what is the last day you checked your repo as 7448

Comment: Did you try checking the `show removed posts` checkbox on your [reputation summary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/488433/bharath?tab=reputation)

Comment: @ Conrad, If any downvote/unaccept, I think it will showing in reputation like -10 or -15. Right?

Comment: @bharath yep that all shows up IIRC that doesn't require you checking the checkbox.

Comment: Moderators are regularly cleaning up old questions that no longer fit in Stack Overflow, for example I lost 10 point due to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783015/) removed where I had answer with one upvote. You will see those changes once ticking "show removed posts". I believe you also lose 2 points for each deleted post you suggested to edit and it was approved which explains the odd change and also lose 2 points when tag gets [burninated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92758/152859) and you suggested its wiki. [example](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/169617)

Comment: I lost 40 points to so heart breaking thanks for the answers and comments on this question helped me to find out what has happend

Comment: I tried checking the reputation history [but it was in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488433/bharath?tab=reputation) and the record of any reputation loss is no longer visible due to system changes. I'm marking this as a duplicate of the canonical CW in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to this link and read it carefully may it helps:

[Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)

There may be very valid reason for this loss of reputation. Have you checked show removed posts checkbox on your reputation summary or your recently answered question.

Maybe the user changed the selected answer or fraud user is deleted who upvoted you or many other reason possible.

Answer (score 5):

Possible reasons:

- The user who voted on your questions was destroyed
- You were serially upvoted, the vote fraud scripts reversed the upvotes.
- You're part of a voting/sockpuppet ring and the votes were invalidated.
- Person who upvoted you, removed their upvote(s).

Comment: @ Sathya, Why its not showing in today reputation like -10 or -15 when user did the downvote/unaccepted answer.

Comment: @bharath i think fraud vote removal not shows on reputaion details but not shure.

Comment: @ Jason, Is it happen on every month?

Comment: @bharath vote fraud scripts run everyday. Also, note that if you put a space between `@` and the username, the user won't get a notification

Comment: @bharath  fraud vote removal and fraud user removal are not monthly based they can be done anytime.It may be a coincident that it happend to you second time after a month.

Comment: @bharath one advise for you, you are not tagging pepole correctly dont place spaces between @ and user name.